# Google Maps infoWindow not placed correctly in jQuery Mobile app

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have a Google Map embedded in a jQuery Mobile app. I get the following behavior when viewing the map on the iPhone and clicking the infoWindows:

1. If I click an infoWindow that requires the map to pan to the left, the right-hand side of the infoWindow falls off of the right-hand side of the screen. [image: Map Panned to the Left]
2. Clicking an infoWindow that requires the map to pan to the right does not have this same problem.[image: Map Panned to the Right]

All infoWindows are sized correctly, but the map simply isn't panning to the right location. I'm using the following code to place the map:

```
<style type="text/css">
.page-map, .ui-content, #map_canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; }
#map_canvas img{max-width:none};
.content-primary, #map_canvas { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
</style>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="mappage" class="page-map" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div data-role="content" class="fullHeight">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to figure out how to get the infoWindows to pan correctly when clicking a marker that causes the map to pan to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-sizing of the windows was causing the issue. I adjusted my CSS to force the info window to be 225 pixels. Once I forced the info window to be smaller than the opening of the iPhone viewport, it properly placed the infoWindow as I expected it to.